# How to query if meta_key does exist or not?

Tags: filters, terms

Good day,
    I am trying to negate my query to show all instead except for a post with a custom field of file gallery.

```
    'meta_query' => array(
                array('key' => 'file_gallery', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '!=')
                )
```

because not all of my post does have this key, and my query seems to work only for those post that has "file_gallery" field with the value of 0 or no 1. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `NOT EXISTS` clause should force `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array('key' => 'file_gallery', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '!='),
        array('key' => 'file_gallery', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
    ),
```